# Is there a "good practice" way of detecting Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, colors, browser-detection

If I were to read the title of this question, having never seen it before, my first response would be, "Don't! Use feature detection instead!", which makes perfect sense, however, it is not a feature I am trying to detect, but instead *how* Firefox renders colors.

For some reason all other browsers I have tested so far render a certain hexadecimal color that appears *between* images beautifully but it appears *lighter* in Firefox.

I have read about possible reasons why (i.e. something about color profiles, which I am just now exploring the topic of) and the "about:config" file here:

> http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/774152
>
> http://jorgebernal.info/2008/03/08/whats-wrong-with-colors-in-firefox/
>
> http://www.maketecheasier.com/28-coolest-firefox-aboutconfig-tricks/2008/08/21

Knowing why is fine, but there seems to be nothing on the topic of how this should be handled by a web-designer (also, it is possible that I am confusing the issue here, because they seem to be talking a lot about images, and the color rendering I am having trouble with is **not** an image, but just a simple hexadecimal color code value).

Here are a couple of screenshots showing the difference between the correctly displayed colors (shown first) and how Firefox renders the colors (shown second). Note the colors *between* each "button" image (which is actually just a 'mousover' drop down box). Also note that the little color that shows between the images are **not** images themselves, just standard CSS rendered hexadecimal colors:

**IE 10:**
[image]

**Firefox 21.0:**
[image]

I am fine with any solution that could get Firefox to display colors the same way that IE and Chrome do (tested on both 32-bit and 64-bit, and still only Firefox does this [on both]), but I know I'm not going to change the "about:config" file for the whole world, so if I could just reliably detect Firefox, perhaps I could just adjust its colors to a darker shade. Unfortunately, I (probably very wisely) never use browser detection, as I know how unstable and unreliable it is.

Is there a reliable (not to mention, future-proof) way to detect Firefox for a web designer? I simply use JavaScript/jQuery for client side scripting.

**--------------------UPDATE---------------------**

Okay, here is the CSS that renders the border colors. The red-is buttons have two classes: DDL and visType, while the grey-ish buttons have the DDL and groupType classes.

```
.DDL.visType
{
    background-color: #bb9191;
    border-right: 2px inset #ba8c8c;
    color: #1a5c17;
}

.DDL.groupType
{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-right: 2px inset #989898;
    color: #0b3773;
}
```

So, you can see there is nothing wrong with this CSS as far as FireFox is concerned. In fact when looking at the true color rendered in Firebug's and Chrome's developer tools both *say* that the actual color rendered is the same for the red-ish buttons' right borders (in rgb it translates to 186, 140, 140).

Comment: You normally shouldn't use JavaScript for css/design specific tasks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by css/design specific tasks? I use jQuery's `.css()` all the time to dynamically change colors, if needed.

Comment: You could also do it the other way around: throw the images out and use `linear-gradient`s instead as backgrounds for your buttons.

Comment: Can you give a link to a test page?

Comment: that sounds like CSS3, though and I have to remain compatible with at least IE 8

Comment: @Graham I don't have it up yet. It isn't done.

Comment: @VoidKing Add classes instead so you get most of the styling into your css files. eg. add a class named hover, selected, drop-zone-active etc.

Comment: @VoidKing You can use a fallback image (with `repeat-x`) for non-supporting browsers. Modern browsers will use the `linear-gradient` while older browsers use the image.

Comment: Again, though really, it isn't the "images" I am having trouble with. If you look carefully you can tell that the image colors are perfectly identical between the two pictures. It is the little color (like a thin vertical bar) that shows up *between* the images that I need changed. The images are fine.

Comment: @VoidKing I know, but I'm thinking that instead of trying to match the colors with the images, you could just as well do away with the images and get rid of the color mismatch problem altogether.

Comment: @NULL Oh, I see, yeah, I suppose you're right. That does keep all the CSS changeable in one place. I will keep that in mind for future designs.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Forgive me, but I suppose I don't get it. If both of the images are displayed correctly and the regular hexadecimal colors are the changing variable... Then it seems it would just render the whole thing too light in Firefox. I like the colors of the images themselves.

Comment: @VoidKing Yes, but at least the *whole thing* would render too light instead of just the image. I know, it would still render the "wrong" colors, but at least your users wouldn't notice (as much) as there's no "jump". Alternatively, you could make the *borders* images as well, but that sounds even worse.

Comment: You're likely just using bad CSS which can be fixed if you give us the CSS code in a test environment (recreate in jsFiddle, for example). Then we will be able to decipher if it's actually Firefox, or your CSS that is the issue.

Comment: @rgthree Well, thanks for the advice, but unless there are certain hexadecimal colors you're not supposed to use for cross-browser reasons, my CSS is just fine. Also, I would be happy to put it on fiddle anyway, but it uses many server-side files, is CMS-ish, and the values are rendered via a database. It would take a LONG time to rewrite the code with static content.

Comment: @rgthree Also, this has been somewhat of an ongoing issue with Firefox, some colors, and my other sites, so it is (unfortunately) not just some typo or an overwritten CSS rule or something like that.

Comment: @VoidKing What I mean is I can tell that looking at your menu it is likely not that the color that is showing incorrectly, but rather something else at play. If you can recreate the issue with _just_ the static HTML & CSS of the menu that's causing the problem, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @rgthree Very possibly so, I suppose. I will try to see if I can work something up without too many hours lost. I wonder how bad it would be to just let it appear differently for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, the problem apparently was how differently Firefox renders the 'inset' border style. Why I had it as inset to begin with is kind of a blur. I was probably testing the various looks on such a thin (`2px;`) border (differences that are barely, if at all, noticeable given the very narrow width).

Once I had changed this style to `solid;`, the color differences were much less drastic:

**Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m:**

[image]

**Firefox 21.0:**

[image]

The same CSS code shown above with the new changes (Only changed both occurrences from `inset` to `solid`):

```
.DDL.visType
{
    background-color: #bb9191;
    border-right: 2px solid #ba8c8c;
    color: #1a5c17;
}

.DDL.groupType
{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-right: 2px solid #989898;
    color: #0b3773;
}
```

A simple solution for a somewhat obtuse problem that should never have occurred in the first place, I suppose (why use `inset` for such a thing anyway?), but narrowing it down was quite difficult.